# Bind to a attached property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have written a attached property which stores amongst others a help text.
This help text is shown on the right side of the main window. This works fine.

Now, I want to add a tooltip for every control. The content of the tooltip should be same as for the helptext extension.

The XAML code:

```
<ListView   ctrl:ListViewLayoutManager.Enabled="true"
            x:Name="ListViewSources"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems}" 
            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyleAlternate}"
            Height="150"
            MinWidth="350" 
            Helper:HelpExtension.IsControl="true"
            Helper:HelpExtension.HelpText="{x:Static strings:GUIResource.HelpProfilesSourcesDescriptionText}" >
    <ListView.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{DynamicResource Own_TooltipStyle}"></ToolTip>
    </ListView.ToolTip>
```

And now the code of the style:

```
<Style x:Key="Own_TooltipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Helper:HelpExtension.HelpText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If I run the program I get the binding error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 :
>   BindingExpression path error:
>   'Helper:HelpExtension' property not
>   found on 'object' ''ListView'
>   (Name='ListViewSources')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Helper:HelpExtension.HelpText;
>   DataItem='ListView'
>   (Name='ListViewSources'); target
>   element is 'TextBlock' (Name='');
>   target property is 'Text' (type
>   'String')

Does anybody know how I can bind the TextBlock to the content of Helper:HelpExternsion.HelpText?

Comment: The code of the style is missing. Please add it by editing your post.

Comment: I assume you mean attached property, not markup extension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put parentheses around the attached property name :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(Helper:HelpExtension.HelpText), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean binding to attached property? In that case you need additional parentheses:

```
{Binding Path=(Helper:HelpExtension.HelpText), ...
```

See, for example, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200917125305/http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/15/binding-to-an-attached-property.aspx).